# Add SVG image to PdfSignatureAppearance with iText7

Tags: svg, itext7

I want to add a SVG image to PdfSignatureAppearance. The method setSignatureGraphic has an ImageData parameter now in iText7. I couldn't find a way to create an imageData from SVG because ImageDataFactory is not supporting this format.

Can you please guide me on how to do that?

Note that with iText5 I was able to add svg after converting it to PDF and import it to a PDFTemplate then create an image after instantiate the PDFTemplate. setSignatureGraphic was accepting com.itextpdf.text.Image as parameter

Answer (score 1):

Your question could be split into 2 more precise and simple ones:

1. How to process an SVG with iText?
2. How to create an ImageData instance out of the result of point 1?

As for question 1: one can use `SvgConverter` class (part of iTextCore's `svg` module). Unfortunately there are only PDF-related methods there: an SVG could be converted either to `Image` (class of `layout` module), or to `PdfFormXObject` (again PDF-related) or to a PDF file.

```
// to PDF
SvgConverter.convertToImage(new FileInputStream(sourceFolder + "your_svg.svg"), signer.getDocument()); // the mentioned `signer` is the instance of PdfSigner which you use to sign the document

// to Image
SvgConverter.convertToImage(new FileInputStream(sourceFolder + "your_svg.svg"), new File(destinationFolder + "svgAsPdf.pdf"));
```

As for question 2, there are several answers:

a) Suppose that you want to use this `Image` as the `PdfSignatureAppearance`'s graphics data. For now the class doesn't provide a convenient setter, however, you could use some low level methods - either `getLayer0` or `getLayer2` to get the signature's background or foreground.  They are represented by `PDfFormXObject`, hence you can use `Canvas` to add your image to them:

```
    Image svg = SvgConverter.convertToImage(new FileInputStream(sourceFolder + "your_svg.svg"), signer.getDocument());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(appearance.getLayer0(), signer.getDocument());
    canvas.add(svg);
    canvas.close();
```

b) Suppose that your goal is to use the rendered bitmap as the `PdfSignatureAppearance`'s graphics data. Then there is a specific iText product - `pdfRender` - which converts PDF files to images. The following code could be applied:

```
PdfToImageRenderer.renderPdf(new File(destinationFolder + "svgAsPdf.pdf"), new File(folderForTheResultantImage));
```

Now you can create an `ImageData` instance out of the resultant image file (by default a PDF is converted to a series of images with the format "pdfnamePAGE_NUMBER.jpg", but one could customize either the name or the output image format). In your case the PDF consist of just one page (which represents the converted SVG) and its name is "image1.jpg". The rest is obvious:

```
appearance.setSignatureGraphic(ImageDataFactory.create(destinationFolder + "image1.jpg"));
```

Comment: I think the op wants to include pdf vector graphics gebraten from his svg into the signature appearance, not a rendered bitmap.

Comment: I want to keep the vector quality of the image inside the signature appearance like I did with iText 5. The mentioned pdfRender way will convert the PDF to jpg so the vector quality will be lost.